# Calculate occurrence of given letter in sentence in Java

Tags: java

```
String sentence = JOptionPane.showInputDialog (null, "Write a sentence.");    
String letter = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Write a letter");

while (true) {

    if (letter.equals("Stop"))
        System.exit(0);    
    //to calculate number of specific character
    else {
        int countLetter = 0;
        int L = letter.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < L; i++) {
            if ((letter.charAt(i) = .....))     
                countLetter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to replace the dots to make the program count how many times the given letter occures in the sentence written in the first string?

Comment: Sure, but it's `==`, not `=` and you may want to cycle through `sentence` too. In other words, you're missing a piece of code other than `.....`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Sandra. Go through your code one more time, I think you have some errors in your thinking here. You are iterating over the characters in `letter`, but `letter` should only contain **one letter**, right? So iterating over its seems like a mistake to me. I think you should replace it with `sentence` in your code and then check `sentence.charAt(i) == letter.charAt(0)`

Answer (score 3):

Since Java 8, there is an elegant solution to this.

```
int count = letter.chars().filter(ch -> ch == 'e').count();
```

This will return the number of occurences of letter 'e'.

Answer (score 0):

if your `String` letter contains a one character use this `letter.charAt(0)` and then replace dots with this. Also remember to use `==` instead of `=` here. `=` means you are just asigning and `==` uses to compare two values.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use a `for` loop and want to stick to the old fashioned way, try this:

```
    String sentence = "This is a really basic sentence, just for example purpose.";
    char letter = 'a';

    int occurrenceOfChar = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++) {
        if (sentence.charAt(i) == letter) {
            occurrenceOfChar++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println("The letter '" + letter
            + "' occurs " + occurrenceOfChar
            + " times in the sentence \""
            + sentence + "\"");
```

> The sentence and the letter are just examples, you have to read the user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Guava](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/CharMatcher.html) Lib to perform this operation faster without iterating string.

```
CharMatcher.is('e').countIn("Write a letter");
```

Will return **3**

Comment: Frankly I would advise against adding an external library for something this trivial.

Comment: You are right but i am just suggesting if they might use the same Lib. @Federico klez Culloca

Comment: I don't think OP is at a point at learning the language, where using libraries is detrimental to their learning progress